# Passing CMD line arguments to docker entry point in Python

Tags: python-2.7, docker

So I've got a docker file like so:

```
FROM frolvlad/alpine-python2
MAINTAINER *REDACTED*
COPY . .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN python misc_scripts/gen_hosts.py
RUN python misc_scripts/strip_delims.py
RUN python runparse.py -spc -spi
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "rebuild.py"]
```

And using the Docker API in python I'm trying to run the container like so

```
logs = client.containers.run(image_id, name=str(_uuid), entrypoint=['-m ME3400', '-mi NONE'])
```

However I get the following error

```
500 Server Error: Internal Server Error ("OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"-m ME3400\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown")
```

I assume I'm doing it wrong, anyone know how/why this isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said in the title of your question, it should be the `command` argument you expect. Follow the [source code on github](https://github.com/docker/docker-py/blob/master/docker/models/containers.py)(starting line 484), it should be more specific.

Change your code as below:

```
logs = client.containers.run(image_id, name=str(_uuid), command=['-m ME3400', '-mi NONE'])
```

Always note that CMD will treat as ENTRYPOINT's args when it exists. But if you specify another ENTRYPOINT(in your case: ['-m ME3400', '-mi NONE']), the original one(["python", "rebuild.py"]) will be overwritten.